# Is login needed after user email verification on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I handle user email verification as in the docs. When user verifies email by clicking the link does he also need to login also? Because after this process when I check it with "firebase.auth().currentUser" on console it returns null. I would expect it would auto login after clicking the verification link.

```
function handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl) {
  // Try to apply the email verification code.
  auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
    // Email address has been verified.

    // TODO: Display a confirmation message to the user.
    // You could also provide the user with a link back to the app.

    // TODO: If a continue URL is available, display a button which on
    // click redirects the user back to the app via continueUrl with
    // additional state determined from that URL's parameters.
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Email verification does not auto-login. It just verifies the user's email.
You have 2 situations here:

1. User opens the link on the same device and it is opened in the same browser where the user initially logged in and sent the email verification, but in a different app. The continue URL takes the user back to a page of the same domain as the page where they initially logged in. In that case the user would be logged in.
2. The user opens the link on a different device or browser. In that case, the user is not logged in. You have to login the user again after they click the continue URL and are redirected to it.

As the email verification may happen on a different domain or the email could have been triggered from a mobile app, logging in the user on the action callback page after verification may be a bad idea and could leave a dangling auth state.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I actually want to trigger some database operations when users verify their emails. But Firebase unfortunately does not listen email verifications and so I decided to handle it with https end point which allows logged-in users only. But it seems when a user clicks the verification link on another device or browser, Firebase does not auto log-in them and so https end point will not allow them. I may think to listen first sign-in of users but Firebase docs say they support only "federated identity provider" not for "email-pass" accounts. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The email verification flow is not a method to sign in users. It is only a mechanism to verify ownership of an email. I have no idea what you are talking about when you say: "Firebase docs say they support only "federated identity provider" not for "email-pass" accounts.". You can pass the action code to an HTTP endpoint where you use the node.js client sdk to `checkActionCode` to get the user info and then `applyActionCode` to complete verification. Only on success, you can use the Firebase Admin node.js SDK to make the database changes you need for that user with admin privileges.